# javascript console in the browser went unresponsive when running my script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wrote a simple script to draw a path on HTML5 canvas, however when running the javascript in chrome:

The longer the path grows (as I draw it), the less responsive the page is, and eventually the javascript console is totally stuck, and I noticed the CPU is almost 100% busy. Could you please give me some hints?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var clickX = new Array();
        var clickY = new Array();
        var clickDrag = new Array();
        var paint;
        var context;

        window.onload =function(){init();}; 

        function init(){
            context = document.getElementById("surface").getContext("2d");

            $('#surface').mousedown(function(e){
                var touchX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var touchY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

                paint = true;
                addClick(touchX, touchY);
                redraw();
            });
            $('#surface').mousemove(function(e){
                if(paint){
                    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
                    redraw();
                }
            });
            $('#surface').mouseup(function(e){
                paint = false;
            });
            $('#surface').mouseleave(function(e){
                paint = false;
            });
        };
        function addClick(x, y){
            clickX.push(x);
            clickY.push(y);
        }

        function redraw(){
            context.strokeStype = "#df4b26";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 5;

            console.log(clickX.length);
            context.beginPath();
            for(var i=0; i<clickX.length;i++){
                context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                console.log(clickX[i]+", "+clickY[i]);
                context.stroke();
            }
            context.closePath();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="surface" style="border:1px solid #000000;"  width="800" height ="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some issues I noticed:

A Demo after refactoring some of your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LStXc/

- You have a typo in redraw (`strokeStype` s/b `strokeStyle`)
- If your project doesn't require saving/reusing the user's polyline then you don't need to save the mouse positions in an array. You can just continuously draw the line by adding a .lineTo with each mousemove event.

*Some performance issues:*

- Calling external functions (as your addClick) are slower than inline commands so consider moving the addClick code into the mousemove handler.
- If your canvas is not being repositioned, you can calculate the offsets once before sketching begins.
- Setting context state (.strokeStyle, .lineJoin, .lineWidth) are relative expensive when repeated in a very active function like a mouse handler.  If your state does not change during the sketch then set these once before sketching begins

*Example Code:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("surface");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#surface").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    var clickX = new Array();
    var clickY = new Array();
    var clickDrag = new Array();
    var paint;
    var context;


        $('#surface').mousedown(function(e){
            var touchX = e.clientX - offsetX;
            var touchY = e.clientY - offsetY;

            paint = true;
            clickX.push(e.clientX-offsetX);
            clickY.push(e.clientY-offsetY);
            lastX=touchX;
            lastY=touchY;
        });
        $('#surface').mousemove(function(e){
            if(paint){
                var x=e.clientX-offsetX;
                var y=e.clientY-offsetY;
                clickX.push(x);
                clickY.push(y);
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(lastX,lastY)
                context.lineTo(x,y);
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();
                lastX=x;
                lastY=y;
            }
        });
        $('#surface').mouseup(function(e){
            paint = false;
        });
        $('#surface').mouseleave(function(e){
            paint = false;
        });


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="surface" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi MarkE. Thank you very much for your analysis and neat sample. Now I understand the issue clearly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Hope this will work for you

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var paint;
        var context;

        window.onload =function(){init();}; 

        function init(){
            context = document.getElementById("surface").getContext("2d");

            $('#surface').mousedown(function(e){
                var touchX =  e.pageX; //e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var touchY = e.pageY; //e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

                paint = true;
                context.beginPath();
                redraw(touchX, touchY);
            });
            $('#surface').mousemove(function(e){
                if(paint){
                    var touchX =  e.pageX; //e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                    var touchY = e.pageY; //e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                    redraw(touchX, touchY);
                }
            });
            $('#surface').mouseup(function(e){
                paint = false;
            });
            $('#surface').mouseleave(function(e){
                paint = false;
            });
        };

        function redraw(nextX,nextY){
            context.strokeStype = "#df4b26";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 5;

            console.log(clickX.length);

                context.lineTo(nextX, nextY);
                console.log(nextX+", "+nextY);
                context.stroke();
            //context.closePath();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="surface" style="border:1px solid #000000;"  width="800" height ="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this redraw function:

```
var actClick = 0;
function redraw(){
    context.strokeStype = "#df4b26";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    console.log(clickX.length);
    context.beginPath();
    actClick = actClick - 2;
    for( ; actClick < clickX.length ; actClick++ ){
        context.lineTo(clickX[actClick], clickY[actClick]);
        context.stroke();
    }
    context.closePath();
}
```

You can find the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLN98/1/)

The problem is that you redraw the wole image every new point, so every new point it will become slower.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It alleviates the unresponsive problem.